# Cython how to import from another package

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cython

I am attempting to extend some `sklearn` classes in the `sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics` module.  However, this entire module is written in Cython, and the things I want to do with my custom class must implement a `cdef dist` (as opposed to a `def dist`), apparently.

Thus, in my own module (I am using jupyter `%%cython` for now, actually) I would like to implement my custom class in Cython, implementing the `cdef dist` method as required.  However, there are a number of other `cdef` things in the same module, in the `sklearn.neighbors.typedefs` module, and possibly in other modules that I need to import. When I try to import those things, I get errors of various sorts.

When I try a naive `import`:

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics import DistanceMetric
from sklearn.neighbors.typedefs import DTYPE_t, ITYPE_t

cdef class NewDistance(sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric):
    cdef inline DTYPE_t dist(self, DTYPE_t* x1, DTYPE_t* x2,
                             ITYPE_t size) nogil except -1:
        return 5
```

I get errors suggesting that once the things have been "pythonized" I cannot use them in a "cython" definition:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
...
First base of 'KernelDistance' is not an extension type
...
'DTYPE_t' is not a type identifier
```

There is a `cimport` keyword, so:

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics cimport DistanceMetric
from sklearn.neighbors.typedefs cimport DTYPE_t, ITYPE_t

cdef class NewDistance(sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric):
    cdef inline DTYPE_t dist(self, DTYPE_t* x1, DTYPE_t* x2,
                             ITYPE_t size) nogil except -1:
        return 5
```

Annnnndddd...

```
Error compiling Cython file:
....
'sklearn/neighbors/dist_metrics.pxd' not found
....
'sklearn/neighbors/typedefs.pxd' not found
```

How does one go about importing cython files from other libraries?

Comment: I tried adding an `__init__.pxd` into the `sklearn` folder and one in the `sklearn/neighbors` folder, then recompiling sklearn, but that does not seem to help.

Comment: is `sklearn` installed in a custom directory?

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf `$pip3 install --user -U .` in the source directory is what I use to install it.  This puts it in `/home/me/.local`

Comment: In order to cimport something, the definition of the thing must be in a pxd file.  When scikit-learn installs, it (as far as I can tell) doesn't copy over the pxd file.  In order to make this work, you'll need to modify your scikit-learn installation by adding the pxd files or you'll need to modify the scikit-learn setup.py script to copy over the pxd files as package_data.

Comment: Here is a relevant issue: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2057

Comment: Given, that scikit-learn doesn't want to expose the internal API, the easiest way would be to copy the  pxd files you need manually into the installation